# Google Sheets - how to find a combination of three items to meet a required value?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a calculator in Google Sheets that will help me find portion sizes of foods to meet a required value.

So say I have:

```
chicken (100g = 32 protein, 0 carb, 1 fat)
avocado (100g = 2 protein, 9 carbs, 15 fat)
rice (100g = 2 protein, 26 carbs, 0 fat)
```

Then let's say I have a required value for that meal to meet 40 protein, 40 carbs, 10 fat.

Is there a formula I can use to find a combination of those three foods so that the sum of each macronutrient meets the required value?

Comment: In Excel I would use the Solver with sumproduct() and an integer constraint.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution in Sheets, why are you using an Excel tag?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I can use either program to solve for it. Excel has some functions Google Sheets does not have (eg. Solver) so I am open to switching over.

Comment: Consider changing your question to take that into account. It reads now that you are looking for a solution in Sheets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Do NOT use with [excel]` Please choose either `Excel` or `Google Sheets`, but not both.